# Configure Chrome Extension at Runtime

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

We're currently building multiple copies of our Chrome CRX, one for each of our dev/test environments, with custom entries in each manifest file.

Often we don't know in advance the hostname of certain test environments prior to building/packaging our code & crx.  Is there a way to pass parameters to a Chrome Extension, or have my Extension read its own filename to look for a naming convention etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to pass arguments to CRX or read extension filename, but you can change extension variables in runtime using Developer Tools console.

Comment: Could you be more specific about how to that please ?